# How would I fix everything on my webpage to appear the same size on diffrerent sized screens?

Tags: css, html, position, size

I'm trying to create a webpage in HTML5 using Notepad++. When I open the page on my laptop it all fits the page well, I have thin red bars as images going across the page, which all fit the screen perfect. However when I open the image on my computer screen, which is larger, the images then don't fit the screen, and stop in the middle of the screen. This is the same with other images and text, which looks stretched. The if I set the sizes to fit my computer screen, they go over the correct position on my laptop. Can anyone help with this please, thanks.

Comment: read about responsive web design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have to search "responsive web design", like Sharemes commented.
I think you want to make your website wholy device-width-responsive.
I recommend to study about "Twitter Bootstrap", which is most widely-used responsive web design css.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behaviour with a .css file

Google something like: "Responsive images with css3"

Have fun learning :)